# AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was wondering if there are any conventions I need to follow if I want to implement twitter bootstrap into my angularJS application or is angular just unobtrusive with twitter bootstrap?

Comment: it's worth noting that the Angular team has Bootstrap as part of it's UI library: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap bootstrap javascript component individually in a directive to make it work. Below is an example to make modal javascript plugin work with angular.

There is an active community [Angular UI bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which does implements bootstrap javascript plugins as Angular directive effectively.

I feel, writing my own directive makes customization easy and no need for heavy javascript library files in your web application.

```
angular.module(app.name).directive('modaldir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    // The linking function will add behavior to the template
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("inside modal");
      element.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = element.attr('href');
        console.log(href);
        $(href).modal();
      });
    }
  };
})
```

**HTML:**

```
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" modaldir class="pull-right password-retrieve"  >Forgot your password?</a>
```

Comment: Actually some statements in this answer are _not_ correct: AngularUI team does _not_ wrap Bootstrap's JavaScripts in directives but rather re-implement those JS components as native AngularJS directives. This is big difference since with the AngularUI approach you don't need to include jQuery nor Bootstrap's JavaScript - you only need Bootstrap's CSS.